# How do I integrate Cppcheck with CMake through CMakeLists.txt files?

Tags: cmake, cppcheck

In Ubuntu I am trying to integrate Cppcheck with CMake through a `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_custom_target(
        cppcheck
        COMMAND /usr/bin/cppcheck *.cpp --xml 2>cppcheck_result.xml
        --enable=warning,performance,portability,information,missingInclude
        --std=c++11
        --library=qt.cfg
        --template="[{severity}][{id}] {message} {callstack} \(On {file}:{line}\)"
        --verbose
        --quiet
        ${ALL_SOURCE_FILES}  
)
add_executable(test hello.cpp)
```

I added the commands above in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the linked question would help to solve your problem. You may need to update your CMake version, but CMake does come with integrated `cppcheck` support. If this - or any other of the available tutorials and answers - does not help you, please describe - in your question - why they don't fit your needs with a concrete description of what you have already tried and the error messages you got.

Comment: I am using CMAKE version 2.8.12 and CPPCHECK vesion 1.61

Comment: I am  trying to invoke cppcheck through CMakeLists.txt file.